# Windows Update is running, but not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, services

I've just installed Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit and I'm trying to run Windows Update, but it refuses to work. When I attempt to check for updates it gives me the message "Windows cannot currently check for updates because the service is not running. You may have to restart your computer."
I've restarted my computer several times with no success. Each time I try to update I'm met with the same message.
In addition, I've gone into Services and checked the status of the Windows Update service and found that it was running. I've successfully restarted the Windows Update service several times but it has no effect. I'm still unable to update.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you run the System Update Readiness Tool? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-is-the-System-Update-Readiness-Tool

Answer (score 0):

If you use a proxy server, you need to setup the proxy settings in windows in the following way:

Open console (cmd) as administrator

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
netsh winhttp set proxy <ip address proxy server>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/windows-update-failing-0xc8000222/6d55c63a-316c-4e9d-97b2-538bc783cdad

It was necessary to roll my update service back to a previous version, if I understand correctly what the instructions had me do.

Comment: Then you would do good by accepting this as the answer even if it's your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and tryied a few options (checking the windows update service is running on regedit, installing directly the SP1 pack, using the windows tool of standalone windows update... but no way!)
Finally I thought installing windows 10... I started the installation but when it started cheking for updates on  the network I stopped the installation.... And now magically windows update is working on windows 7! :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Windows Update service does not work in deed. Open cmd as administrator and type net stop wuauserv - it stops Windows Update service and then net start wuauserv - it starts service once again, you can check updates again. On the other hand you can check in gpedit.msc if Auto updates is turned on. Press start and type gpedit.msc in search box ten goto: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update find Turn on recommended updates via Automatic updates - double click and make sure if it's Enabled.